# Expression is not Assignable, Assigning x and y Values to the Points of a Shape

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating an SFML application and need to randomly assign the x and y values of the points that make up a sf::Circleshape. I am using the circle shape to construct any regular sided polygon.

However, when I try to assign the x and y values to the points of the circle I get the error "expression is not assignable"

The code the gives this error is:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < numSides; i++){
                shape.getPoint(i).x = xDistrib(point);
                shape.getPoint(i).y = yDistrib(point);
 }
```

numSides being the number of sides for the shape, and xDistrib and yDistrib both being random number generators.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: My guess is that `getPoint(i)` returns a struct. If the compiler allowed the assignment to `x`, say, that would work, but the temp struct would then be thrown away afterwards, leaving the code with no external effect.

Comment: the only question i see is "How does the missing code look to reproduce the error?". Please include a [mcve] and the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify shape, consider returning a reference from getPoint() and the error will probably be gone.
But you may want to actually add a setter to your class which looks like that:

```cpp
void setPoint(int i, int x, int y);
```

This is more "object oriented".